# magento backend url not working

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I'm totally lost here, I have several Magento installations where the backend url doesn't work nice.

The problem is this:

In the frontend, all urls are perfectly rewritten so `index.php` is not in the url and mod_rewrite works.

but for the admin part, all urls that are created have the `index.php` part still in there, in a normal installation it wouldn't be a problem put now, a url like `index.php/admin/dashboard` results in a 404 error page. But, the funny part is that when I remove the `index.php` part of the url, it works.

I fixed this problem with a few .htacces tricks and hacks, but I find these hacks no good. Some parts of the backend still won't work or need their own .htacces redirect, or won't work at all even with the redirect in .htacces.

So, my questions are: Why are my Magento installations giving 404 errors on a `index.php/admin` call? And how to **nicely** get rid of the `index.php` part in the backend urls, without .htacces hacks?

The Magento version for all shops is 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple, add "AcceptPathInfo On" to apache configuration.

Credits: http://www.magentocommerce.com/answers/discussion/178/index.phpinstall-was-not-found/p1